# Django filter a many-to-many list of IDs

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to filter a many-to-many feild on a model where I'm give a comma separated list of ids in the URL...

> ids = 3,7

```
cat_ids = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('cat_ids', None)
super(Filter, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs).filter(categories__id_in=cat_ids)
```

> Error: TypeError: Related Field got invalid lookup: id_in

Is this possible if so how?

Comment: try super(Filter, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs).filter(categories__id__in=list(cat_ids))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `categories__id__in` (double underscore).

See [Django documentation: QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in).

UPDATE: If with

> a comma separated list of ids

you mean a comma separated *string* of ids, then you should:

```
cat_ids = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('cat_ids', None).split(',')
```

Comment: Trying the above gives the error: ``invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','``

Comment: I also tried turning it into a list ``list(cat_ids)`` but get the same error

Comment: I got no idea what `self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get` returns if you don't say.